# iOS5, banshee and memories gone

Tags: banshee, iphone

I am new to Linux and while syncing my iPhone 4 iOS 5 with Banshee, I have transferred 2 gbs of music and then I could not see any music in my iPhone. I only realised shortly after that Banshee currently does not support iOS 5. However somehow the 2gb of music have been transferred into my iPhone, and I cannot figure out a way to delete this wasted storage. My iTunes says that 2gb of storage is being used under "Other" caDoes anyone know how to track the music transferred into my iphone and delete the files?

Thanks in advance.

Steven

Comment: You need to reset/restore the iPhone from iTunes. Do you have all the files & music backed up in iTunes? Make sure you do before doing this, so you don't lose everything.

Answer (score 2):

There may or may not be a couple of ways of doing this.

First off you could use nautilus to navigate your iphone into the `/iTunes_Control/Music/` folder. There you should find folders named `Fxx`. When inspecting these folders you should try to find files named `lipgodxxxxxx` as opposed to the iTunes synched files which should be named with 4 capital letters.

The `lipgodxxxxxx` files are the ones uploaded onto the phone via banshee.

Once you're at this step and you've asserted that this is indeed the case you can either browse all folders and remove them manually or use the following command:

```
find ~/.gvfs/XXXXX/iTunes_Control/Music -name "libgpod*" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Where `XXXXX` is the device's name (as it shows in the nautilus sidebar)